# SQL select groups where values are exclusively in a list

Tags: sql

Given a table with two columns, department and employee, where every employee belongs to 1 department.

Given a list of employee ids, how do I select departments where all employees are in the list?

| Department | Employee |
| --- | --- |
| finance | 1 |
| finance | 2 |
| marketing | 3 |
| marketing | 4 |
| IT | 5 |
| IT | 6 |

given `(2,3,4,5,6)`, returns `('marketing', 'IT')`

(Note: DB flavor does not matter to me, you may use standard or DB-specific SQL)

Comment: Honestly this is going to be such a complicated query, I would do the "logic" with third party server-side programming and `CREATE` a temp table for that data to be read from.

Comment: This is a classic relational division problem. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/ "Ain't no plane in this hangar I can't fly" ~ "Aint no employee I employ not in this list"

Comment: @Zak it's a clearly defined problem in one table, can it be that complicated?

Comment: Look at your answers .. Yes it can be that complicated :)

Comment: -- And *1 table* that's the problem that **makes** it complicated.. It's a relational issue .. Where you probably should have 3 tables.  `Department` | `Employee` -- Each with their respective ID's .. And a `employee_to_department` table that defines a row for `employee_id` and `department_id` -- Thus being able to query with a single `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Put your input id's into a table, join to the existing table, and check counts between input and the existing employees. If they match, output.

Change this to whatever RDBMS you're using

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE input_vals (id int); 
insert into input_vals 
values 
(2), 
(3), 
(4), 
(5), 
(6); 

with cte_joins AS (
    select ot.department, 
    count(ot.employee) AS employee_count1, 
    sum(case when iv.id is not null then 1 else 0 end) AS employee_count2

    from orig_table ot
    left join input_vals iv
        on ot.employee = iv.id

    group by ot.department
)
select department 
from cte_joins
where employee_count1 = employee_count2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you employee list is captured as a column in a table. Since you didn't provide any detail on the tool set you are using.

Something like this is a common pattern, depending on your dbms there's other more simple syntax.

```
select distinct
       de.department
  from department_employee de
 where not exists
         ( select 1
             from department_employee de2
            where not exists
                    ( select 1
                        from employee_list el
                       where de2.employee = el.employee
                    )
              and de.department = de2.department
         );
```

Comment: hi, so far only your answer and mine are concise and readable, and solve the problem. do you have any objection if I accept my answer to be correct because, it uses indexes and correlated subqueries don't?

Comment: @kakarukeys Glad you sorted it out. Just for devil's advocate, as a rule of thumb I absolutely never use NOT IN and wrote the query this way to avoid it. It can have very counterintuitive behavior when NULLs are are in the mix so it's a safer bet to never use it, lest you have to remember to handle nullability on a case by case basis. https://www.polderknowledge.nl/2018/03/02/sql-beware-null-where-not/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of derived tables - one to get the count of employees in each department and one to get the count of employees in each department limited by your list of employees. Return the ones that match.

```
select
distinct full_list.department
from (
  select
  department,
  count (*) as cnt
  from
  <your table>
  group by department) full_list
  inner join (
  select
  department,
count (*) as cnt
from
<your table>
group by department
where
employee in (2,3,4,5,6)
 ) limited_list
on full_list.department = limited_list.department
and full_list.cnt = limited_list.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- departments
select department from t where employee in (2,3,4,5,6);

-- departments containing extra persons
select department from t 
where department in (select department from t where employee in (2,3,4,5,6))
      and employee not in (2,3,4,5,6);

--- departments, employees from the list, with no extra
select department from t 
where employee in (2,3,4,5,6) and department not in (
    select department from t 
    where department in (
        select department from t where employee in (2,3,4,5,6)
    ) and employee not in (2,3,4,5,6)
)
```